# unable to get all methods of a SAP di api object using Reflection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reflection, business-objects

I was trying to display all the methods of `SAPbobsCOM.Items` using the following code:

```
 SAPbobsCOM.Items item = (SAPbobsCOM.Items)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oItems);
        Type t = item.GetType();
        MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of methods={0}", mi.Length);
        foreach (MethodInfo m in mi)
            Console.WriteLine(m);
```

The output gives only 7 methods and excludes several other available methods including the `Add()` , `Update()`methods, though it is displayed by intellisense while writing the code. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the SAP interface but here are a few possible causes:

1. [`Type.GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx) returns only public methods. It looks like you are evaluating a COM object so other types of methods are unlikely.
2. For COM objects, methods could be omitted from the metadata or included in different COM interfaces.
3. Other methods may be [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) added by other classes. Once again, unlikely if this is a COM object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply reflect COM object by this way. You can do it by:

1) Using TLI.DLL (type library information) or
2) Reflect interop.SAPbobsCOM.dll, which is a .net dll.

Li